# set default value/auto-populate required close date field when creating new opportunity

Tags: workflow, opportunity, date, required-field

When a user creates a new Opportunity the Close Date field is required to be entered. However, the requirement is to automatically set this field to 1 date from when the opportunity is created. I handle this via a on creation workflow rule. But, since this field is a standard required field on the Opportunity object I cannot remove it from the page layout and users must but a date even though it'll be updated upon creating the record.

Is there anyway to make it so when a new Opportunity is being created ANY value is defaulted into this field so the user doesn't have to put anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: In classic it can be done through url hacking not possible in lightning. You need to override the new button with custom code.

Comment: [Spring 20 introduces "URL hacking" to Lightning](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm) - just a few days away